# i get this error when iam trying to include Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart to my laravel project :

Tags: php, laravel

I want to include the package [Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) to my laravel project but when I run:

```
composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart
```

this error shows:

> Using version ^2.6 for gloudemans/shoppingcart
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 requires illuminate/events 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.21, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.21].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using in your application?

Comment: @thisiskelvin  im using Laravel Framework 5.8.21

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the package maintainer has not added support for laravel 5.8. This can be seen in the package's `composer.json` file.

```
"require": {
    "illuminate/support": "5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.*",
    "illuminate/session": "5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.*",
    "illuminate/events": "5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.*"
},
```

To get this working, you could fork the repository to your own github account, add the `5.8.*` dependancy required for your project and install your version of the package into your project using the git repository in your `composer.json` file (see [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)).

Comment: ok ill try to do that , thank you so much , otherwise do you know another package for shoppingcart that support 5.8 laravel version so i can save some time, im really stack  here

Comment: i found the same issue , but i find another package that support 5.8 : bumbummen99/shoppingcart , thank you

Comment: Welcome @SoumiaElhali, if you feel this helped please mark question as correct.